# Non-official usb-c dock station detects 2 external monitors are a single one

Tags: macbook-pro, display, driver, video-adapter

I bought this dock station [USB-C JF68](https://www.azdome.hk/usb-c-hub-hdmi.html)  and everything works besides HDMI+Display port simultaneously.

The site claims this thing supports MacBook (I'm using 16" Pro). And it also claims that it supports 2 video outputs in extended mode simultaneously. Giving the fact that Macbook also claims that it supports 2 video outputs from a single thunderbolt (on each side of the laptop) I rely on that this station supports my Mac.

But when I attach both ports together I get mirrored output to both of my external displays (I mean both of them work, but the image is exactly the same). Nevertheless, they are still extended from Macbook's integrated one. If I get to Display arrangement settings in macOS I see that it only detects both displays as a single one. here's the image the display with white border is my integrated one, and the right one is actually both of my external displays.

[image]

I use HDMI->HDMI cable and FDP->FDP (Full-size display port). So there are no intermediate parts. The both external monitors run at 1920x1080@60Ghz (Acer v226hql (HDMI) + MSI optix g24c (Display port).

I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.2, which I updated yesterday, so all drivers are up to date. I'm not sure if they're some official Azdome driver because I haven't found any.

The interesting part that this exact adapter outputs both displays in extended mode ok for my MSI laptop which runs Archlinux. So the adapter is definitely working. The issue is probably with drivers. I also asked apple support they say that they guarantee that their software drivers only work on official adapters that I can only buy on apple.com.

All of the other things work ok (ethernet/USB/power delivery/ audio). I also tried to plug off every other thing from the adapter and tried to run only with HDMI+DP connected but it just doesn't matter.

I also have another cheap adapter usb-c->hdmi+usbc+usb which when I connect to the same side to the same external monitor works.

Well, that thing described above only works like that only ~50% of the time. Another 50% MacBook just doesn't detect both screens at all. (I mean display arrangement tab is missing from display settings, and they are both black). In all 100% cases all other interfaces from this dock station work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup you with that hardware is not going to work - and cannot be made to work.

The USB-C dock station you've got works as a MST (Multi-Stream Transport) hub. MST is a part of the DisplayPort 1.2 standard, which makes it possible for monitors and computers to support "daisy-chaining".

Daisy-chaining is most often seen where the monitor has both an input and output DisplayPort adapter, allowing you to connect the first monitor to the computer, and the second monitor to the first monitor. If both monitor and computer support MST daisy-chaining the two displays will act as seperate displays, exactly like if they had been plugged in directly to the computer.

In this case MST daisy-chaining is used within the dock to allow dual monitor outputs. Note that because the monitors share bandwidth, it is not possible to connect them at the same resolutions and refresh rates as possible when using seperate cables connected to the computer. With your monitors it shouldn't be a problem though (they're relatively low res).

The problem for you is that macOS does not support MST daisy-chaining. This is a software limitation and not a hardware limitation. Instead macOS supports daisy-chaining Thunderbolt monitors (such as with the Apple Thunderbolt Monitor).

You've got it working on your ArchLinux laptop because Linux supports MST. In fact you should be able to run Linux on your MacBook Pro and drive both displays via MST that way.

To get a setup like this working with  macOS, you'll need a Thunderbolt 3 dock instead of a USB-C dock. Or you could individually connect the displays to the MacBook Pro. For example one display connected to the dock, and the other connected via a USB-C to DisplayPort cable.

Comment: > you'll need a Thunderbolt 3 dock instead of a USB-C 
Do you mean thunderbolt rather than usb 3.0? as I understood usb-c is not an "interface" despite everyone says (a standard that defines how data transfers), but rather a hardware socket. Which I think makes thunderbolt backwards compatible with usb 3.2. So since usb 3.0-3.1 don't support transmitting video channels, this makes that this station has a thunderbolt port, rather than usb 3.x. CRIIR, links are appreciated. Thanks for the MST tip, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Well, I meant "get a Thunderbolt 3 dock". It's not a good idea to get a "Thunderbolt dock" (i.e. the old version of Thunderbolt) - it will not do the trick. The USB dock you've got now will not be compatible with macOS for doing extended desktop over two separate monitors. And no, I did not mean "USB 3.0" - I meant specifically "USB-C". You have only half of the story with your "interface/socket" explanation (a "standard" that defines how data is transferred is not really called an interface, but an protocol - but that's just details). The big difference is that with the USB-C connector, [...]

Comment: [...] you have something called Alternate Mode. This means that the same cable transfers not only the USB protocol, but also something else - which can be for example DisplayPort, HDMI, etc. The display signal for your dock is NOT sent via the USB protocol, but over USB-C via the Alternate Mode pins. Your dock definitely do NOT have a Thunderbolt port. I don't know why you detail that USB 3.2 supports transferring video channels where USB 3.0-3.1 don't - that's not true at all. In fact, USB 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2 does not support transferring HDMI/DisplayPort natively, [...]

Comment: [...] however you can transfer "video channels" over them using technologies that encode the video signal in USB packets. The most common solution here is DisplayLink. Your dock does not support DisplayLink.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I mean no Usb support video channel, including 3.0, 3.1, 3.2. So is there a thunderbolt adapter (which uses usb-c) that supports 2 displays simultaneously on mac? If yes, which techs should I search for. let's say I want to find it on eBay.

Comment: Yes, you can find lots of Thunderbolt 3 docks that does this. For example the OWC Thunderbolt docks. The tech used is just Thunderbolt 3.

Comment: Can't find any docking station there that supports 96+W of PD required by mac16" and dual monitor support.

Comment: The 16” MacBook Pro does not “require” 96W PD - that is a misconception. For example I’m using an OWC Thunderbolt 3 dock with 2 x 4K monitors at 60 Hz with 85W PD, which is just fine.

Comment: If a dock station supports an hdmi and another thunderbolt out, can I attach a 2nd monitor to this thunderbolt via another adapter? Would it always work? Does it require some characteristics from dockstation? Same question applies to usb-c out. WOuld it wourk if mac -> dock station with hdmi, usbc -> hdmi -hdmi, usb-c -> hdmi

Comment: If it’s a Thunderbolt 3 dock, then yes, this is how these usually work. Check the documentation for your particular dock if you’re in doubt. You often do not even need an adapter, as you can get a simple cable with USC-C in one end, and DisplayPort at the other end. Usually you cannot do extended desktop with 2 monitors using an USB-C from a docking station - that’s usually just mirrored. Exceptions are DisplayLink for example, but that’s not at all preferable.

Comment: Could you please share a link to the station you have. Would [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/OWC-Thunderbolt-3-Dock-14-Port-Cable-Compatible-with-Windows-PC-Mac-Space-Gray/264615731177?hash=item3d9c539fe9:g:u3AAAOSwyjNdOndZ) one work. Where can I find DC In 20V 9A? Would lower power work with DC iN (I mean any lower power supply with 20v output)? I don't think the seller could answer those questions and as it turned out neither official site can.

Comment: The one you linked is the one I have. They also have a Pro model of the same, and there’s 7-8 other companies who make similar docks (like Belkin for example). The power supply comes with the dock, so that’s not something you need to supply.

Comment: So you would recommend this one, [PRO](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-pro-dock) only supports 60w

Comment: No, I'm not recommending the PRO. I don't what you need to use it for, so I can't say if the best for you is an OWC, Belkin, Elgato, Belkin, StarTech, HP, Plugable, IoGear, Akitio, or something else. There's lots of Thunderbolt 3 docks out there - you can just google for reviews. If 96W of power was important for you, then obviously choose the 85W 14-port OWC model over the 60W Pro model.

Comment: Just noting that Hyper released some new docks now that have 100W power delivery - if you want to be able to run it at 96W...